Highcharts Piechart 3D Tooltip not showing on slice/chart hover
I am not able to see the tooltip on hover of slices in 3d pie chart.
Even the site example at https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/3d-pie is not showing tooltip. V11.4.6
Is there any value that I have to set to be able to see this tooltip.
It is working on lower version but on these versions, I am not able to remove the functionality where when we click on a legend the slice associated with it gets removed.

It's a regression bug that occured in the newest Highcharts version. The workaround for now is to set pointer-events to auto with important flag: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mj92683y/
It will be fixed in the next release of Highcharts.
Link to the issue on GH: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/21569
#container {
 height: 400px;
 pointer-events: auto !important;
}

